# Kerberos settings for Windows environment

Tags: windows, ssh, kerberos

We do have below Windows env with Kerberos enabled-

```
Machine A - KDC,
Machine B - Sftp windows service
Machine C - Client from where are trying to connect through ssh command.
```

When we are trying to connect to Sftp windows service through ssh command, we able to connect with appropriate KDC credentials. But it didnt ask me for Kerberos credentials prompt. Its just executed smoothely on 'password' Authencation mode and showing below me authentication mode log

```
INFO: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
```

And didnt show me the log like below (with gssapi)and didnt ask for Kerberos credentials (prompt).

```
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
```

So I am not sure, what we are missing in Kerberos enviornment. Can someone please help us on this.

Thanks,
Hrushi